# CROSSTAB SQL State: 42804

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I'm trying to familiarize myself with CROSSTAB, but I keep getting an error.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
    CROSSTAB('SELECT
                   1,
                   2,
                   3')
     AS (one NUMERIC, two NUMERIC, three NUMERIC)
```

```
ERROR:  invalid return type
DETAIL:  SQL rowid datatype does not match return rowid datatype.
SQL state: 42804
```

Comment: in return type of Crosstab all columns are mentioned as NUMERIC but data returned by select query is in INT. Make both type same.

Comment: add your example data and desired output